# Oracle Server 11g: How Can I Disable Remote Connections?

Tags: oracle, connection

How can I disable remote connections to Oracle Server 11g?
The one way, I can use firewall for port 1521.
Is it possible to disable remote connections and leave just local connection for Oracle Server without firewall but only with Oracle Server settings?
For example, SQL Server 2008 (Express) has service for remote connections: SQL Browser. If it is not running, it is impossible to connect to server remotely.
Is it similar way for Oracle Server?

Answer (score 3):

You can set your listener up on address `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which will mean it's only visible from that machine. There will be nothing to firewall - there will be nothing listening on port 1521 on the machine's external IP address. You can confirm that with `netstat`.

You can't directly do it from within the database, if that's what you mean by 'only with Oracle Server settings'; all remote connections come through the listener and are handed off to the database.

Comment: It was my first idea to change to 127.0.0.1. I changed settings for listener (with help Oracle Net Manager): Protocol: TCP/IP; Host: localhost (or 127.0.0.1); Port: 1521. It became impossible to connect remote and locally...

Comment: How are you connecting locally? (And what does 'locally' mean - which client(s) are you using?) What connection settings?

Comment: It means, that I have Windows Server with Oracle Server. I need to do: it is possible to connect with desktop application (personal) to Oracle Server locally (from this Windows Server); it is impossible to connect to Oracle Server from another computer(s) of local network.

Comment: @Chaki_Black - Yes, as long as the application is connecting to `localhost` too. In SQL Developer, for example, you'd need to change the connect to point to `127.0.0.1`; if you're using Java then the JDBC connect string would need to replace your PC name or IP address with `127.0.0.1`; if you're using something that relies on TNS resolution then you'd need to update your `tnsnames.ora` to have the TNS alias point to `127.0.0.1`. I guess you have something that's still using the server name, so you'd need to find it and change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to be able to connect locally, don't start the Oracle Listener and only use ORACLE_SID to connect to the database. As long as a listener is running, remote access to the database is possible.

You don't explain why you have this requirement, so I start guessing. Being able to do application maintenance could be a good reason. If that is the case, why not work with restricted session privileges ? In that case, set the instance in restricted session so only users having restricted session privilege can connect to the database instance. Normally only specific administrator accounts should have this privilege.

```
alter system enable restricted session;
```

- stop existing session that should not live during maintenance.
- do the maintenance.

  alter system disable restricted session;

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Keeping 'listener' down is good option of restricting DB access from remote clients/machines during maintenance window.

Comment: Can use lsnrctl stop; and lsnrctl start; for the same.